# Do browsers ever open multiple sockets for GET requests?

Tags: network-programming

Say, if my browser is downloading a large image file, is there ever a case where it will split up the request over multiple sockets?

Or is this a moot question, since it'd require that level of functionality from the corresponding webserver..?

Comment: Some "download managers" will do this, but yes, it requires that the server support restarting file downloads from a specific position.  In general, the browsers themselves don't do this but third party tools might.